# If hasClass help and subtracting from variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make it so when the '.main' is clicked, it will toggle its class to become a '.second', with this new class it will become red but the element will have already been classed as '.main' already, thus, I can still refer to it as '.main'. After that I want it to add to the 'count' variable and, if clicked again, revert back to the appearance of the '.main' class, then subtracting from the 'count' variable!

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="box" class="main"></div>
  <div id="box" class="main"></div>
  <div id="box" class="main"></div>
  <div id="box" class="main"></div>
</div>
```

relevent css

```
.main {
  background: #888888;
}
.second {
  background: red;
}

#box {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  margin: 1% 1%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

And, jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var count = 0;

  $('.main').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('second')
    $(this).toggleClass('main')

    if ($(this).hasClass('main')) {
      count++;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('second')) {
      count--;
    }
    if (count === 4) {
      alert('Success')
    }
  });
});
```

So I need help because the jQuery will keep adding to the 'count' variable even if 'this' hasClass '.second'!

*IF YOU THINK YOU HAVE AN ANSWER CHECK IT IN JSFIDDLE AND CLICK THE ONE BOX 4 TIMES, IF YOU GET A PROMPT THEN THE 'COUNT--;' ISN'T SUBTRACTING STILL*

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Comment: as I just edited in, even if the class is 'second' it still adds to the 'count' if I click on it.

Comment: At first, you are toggling the class `.main`. Is that what you expected?

Comment: Why do you toggle twice ?

Comment: firstly, you cannot have same ID for multiple elements

Comment: when I click on the .main I want it to toggle it a .second whilst adding to the 'count' variable set. It does that, but it doesn't subtract from the 'count' variable if I click the .second, it has just become.

Comment: +Dhiraj I couldn't need the ID for the jQuery less, but I do for the css, And with that it works... sooo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to change these.

1. Remove the `count` variable and instead use jQuery's length.
2. Do not use the same value for `ID`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.main').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('second').toggleClass('main')

    if ($('.main').length == 4)
      alert('Success')
  });
});
```

```css
.main {
  background: blue;
}
.second {
  background: red;
}

#box1, #box2, #box3, #box4 {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;

  margin: 1% 1%;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="box1" class="main"></div>
  <div id="box2" class="main"></div>
  <div id="box3" class="main"></div>
  <div id="box4" class="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped the problem I am currently having, but is there anyway, using the way that I'm doing it, that would work too.

Comment: Yes, you can do it by toggling it later, after setting the count value.

Comment: Also you should **never** use the same ID value for more than one element.

Comment: Yes I do know, but since it was a very small project, and giving them all different ID's then listing them in a array took too long. But, with that in mind I could have just given them all a second class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `$(this).toggleClass('main')` from within `$('.main').click(function() {` updating the code to

```
$('.main').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('second')

    if ($(this).hasClass('second')) {
      count++;
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('main')) {
      count--;
    }
    if (count === 4) {
      alert('Success')
    }
});
```

when you toggle the `.main` class it is removed and it will not fall within the click call

And you can't have multiple items with the same ID within your HTML, you can assign class if it occurs more than once. See the fiddle linked below for an example of how you can have it

jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/ks14dnL1/4/

Comment: This still adds to the count variable even though the 

else if ($(this).hasClass('second')) {
      count--;
    }


should be subtracting from it!

Comment: @BenHalford Sorry about that my bad, i see you got your solution but i am updating the fiddle and the answer as a refference for anyone else looking for this :)

Comment: In the end I found it was that instead of count--;  I had  count++; so I noticed the mistake on the question, thus I corrected it, forgetting about correcting in the .js file. That among some other mistakes I didn't notice!